# How to use R dplyr's summarize to count the number of rows that match a criteria?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, counting, summarize

I have a dataset that I want to summarize. First, I want the sum of the home and away games, which I can do. However, I also want to know how many outliers (defined as more than 300 points) are within each subcategory (home, away).

If I wasn't using summarize, I know `dplyr` has the `count()` function, but I'd like this solution to appear in my `summarize()` call. Here's what I have and what I've tried, which fails to perform:

```
#Test data
library(dplyr)

test <- tibble(score = c(100, 150, 200, 301, 150, 345, 102, 131),
                  location = c("home", "away", "home", "away", "home", "away", "home", "away"),
                  more_than_300 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))


#attempt 1, count rows that match a criteria
test %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  summarize(total_score = sum(score),
            n_outliers = nrow(.[more_than_300 == FALSE]))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sum` on logical vectors - it will automatically convert them into numeric values (`TRUE` being equal to 1 and `FALSE` being equal to 0), so you need only do:

```r
test %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  summarize(total_score = sum(score),
            n_outliers  = sum(more_than_300))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   location total_score n_outliers
#>   <chr>          <dbl>      <int>
#> 1 away             927          2
#> 2 home             552          0
```

Or, if these are your only 3 columns, an equivalent would be:

```r
test %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), sum))
```

In fact, you don't need to make the `more_than_300` column - it would suffice to do:

```r
test %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  summarize(total_score = sum(score),
            n_outliers  = sum(score > 300))
```

Answer (score 4):

In base R, we can try `aggregate` like this

```
> aggregate(.~location,test,sum)
  location score more_than_300
1     away   927             2
2     home   552             0
```

Answer (score 3):

In base `xtabs` could be used to sum up per group.

```
xtabs(cbind(score, more_than_300) ~ ., test)
#location score more_than_300
#    away   927             2
#    home   552             0
```

Or by calculating the outliers on the fly and giving desired column names.

```
xtabs(cbind(total_score = score, n_outliers = score > 300) ~ location, test)
#location total_score n_outliers
#    away         927          2
#    home         552          0
```

Another option, also in base, will be `rowsum`.

```
with(test, rowsum(cbind(total_score = score, n_outliers = score > 300), location))
#     total_score n_outliers
#away         927          2
#home         552          0
```

`xtabs` and `rowsum` are specialized in calculating sums per group and might be performant in this task.